What do the coloured lines mean below cargo on the Station Report screen?
I've read the manual but I can't seem to find the specific meaning for these multi-coloured lines beneath the cargo in the "Waiting for pickup" section on the Station Report screen:

Could anybody tell me what they mean?  They seem to roughly correspond to the wagons beside the cargo name in terms of length, but can be coloured a combination of dark green, red, and light green.
